# Can Math.random be replaced with a CSPRNG that generates a number with the same parameters?

Tags: javascript, random, cryptography

I want to replace the `Math.random` function with a cryptographically-secure random number generator.

The generator's output must be from `0` (inclusive) to `1` (exclusive) to be consistent with the original `Math.random`, so it can be dropped into any project without potentially causing errors.

Answer (score 1):

A function like this will do the trick:

```js
Math.random = () => (crypto || msCrypto).getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / 4294967296
```

Source: [For a more secure implementation...](https://web.archive.org/web/20190624215423/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues#Examples)

Explained: By feeding a `Uint32Array` into the `getRandomValues` method, we generate a cryptographically-secure random number between `0` and `4294967295`. By dividing this output by `4294967296`, the resulting number will be between `0` (inclusive) and `1` (exclusive) just like `Math.random`.

Comment: I don't think you want to subtract 1 from Math.pow(2,32) unless you want 1 *included* in the range of possible outputs.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage fixed

Comment: Sorry if I'm ignorant, but what does `inclusive && (integerLimit -= 1);` do, and why is it needed?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I realized that it was sort of pointless, since it defeats the purpose of the question (re-creating `Math.random` with a CSPRNG) so i got rid of it. Thanks for sorta pointing that out.

Comment: In hindsight I get what it does, but as the variable was defined *outside* the function and was not listed as parameter I was wrong-footed. Glad you got it fixed, if just for clarity.